# Is there a way in bulk email to restrict the from email address to just that user?

Tags: civimail

We have several people who can send bulk email.  Each user can select any of the from's we've added.  Really only certain people should be able to send mail from some other user.

It looks like this question has sort of been asked but then it came back as no and it should maybe be a feature request.  The question is a couple of years old so maybe something has changed in that time or maybe people have figured out a work around.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: This extension is unmaintained and not recommended. <strike>You want the [From Email Address Permission](https://civicrm.org/extensions/from-email-address-permission) extension.</strike>

Comment: Maybe I'm clueless, but I can't for the life of figure out how to use this. I install it and I see the addition relationship thing and roles in the from email screen. If I read it correctly and say add the role of administrator to one of the from email addresses, anyone logged who is not an admin shouldn't see that from address. Yet they do.

Comment: Yeah, this was a bad suggestion.  There's an [open feature request](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/198).  It's possible to programmatically change a list of drop-down options with hook_civicrm_fieldOptions.  So a developer could probably make a custom extension for you in an hour or less, but a true replacement for this extension (providing a GUI for non-developers to set up their own permissioning) would be more work.

Comment: I'm guessing it worked with older versions of civicrm.  I've done a couple of hooks things.  Maybe I'll take a stab at it.